# Getting the second paragraph in html - iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, paragraph, nsscanner

I am making an app which will get text from a website I have got this code so far

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rss.cnn.com"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];

    // Assuming data is in UTF8.
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    show.text = string;


    NSString *webString = show.text;
    NSScanner *stringScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:webString];
    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] init];
    while ([stringScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        [stringScanner scanUpToString:@"<p>" intoString:Nil];
        [stringScanner scanUpToString:@"</p>" intoString:&content];


        show.text = content;
    }


}
```

As you can see I am trying to capture the paragraph and that has worked it pulls the first paragraph from the website, when I see all the html code I see there are more than one `<p>` / paragraphs like it has a `<p> (some text) </p> (Some other code) <p> (some text) </p>`

My app only captures the first paragraph how can I make it so the app can capture the second paragraph as well? Thank you!

Comment: so, What you want, You want to remove the <p> from your string ?

Comment: No, I want to be able to extract the second paragraph from the html. Because I can only get the first paragraph with the code I have used.

Comment: I ran your code and the problem is that the html contains no `<p>` only `<p`

Comment: Could you please write an answer on how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using regular expressions. Use following code,

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\<p>(.*?)\\</p>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

NSString *webString = show.text;

NSArray *myArray = [regex matchesInString:webString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [webString length])] ;

NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[myArray count]];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in myArray) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    [matches addObject:[webString substringWithRange:matchRange]];

    NSLog(@"%@", [matches lastObject]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work. I didnt get the second paragraph in the code.

Comment: Show whole content of your webString. I'll check on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for you help but I only want to get the 2nd paragraph from the html code. :)